# Join multi table and get result by mutli bdoup by column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want result from three table with multi column groupby

Table 1

```
| Id| pr_id| c_id| 
|---|------|-----|
| 1 |  33  |  18 |
| 2 |  33  |  19 |
| 3 |  34  |  18 |
```

Table 2

```
|Id| pr_id| qty| 
|--|------|----|
|1 | 33   |  22|
|2 | 33   |  10| 
|3 | 34   |  12|
```

Table 3

```
|c_id| l_id| 
|----|---- |
| 18 |  1  |
| 19 |  2  |
```

And i want result like this

```
|total_qty| 1(l_id)| 2(l_id)|pr_id| 
|---------|--------|--------|-----|
| 32      |  22    |   10   |  33 |
| 12      |  12    |   0    |  34 |
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but it likely happened because you showed no effort.

Comment: For pr_id 33: How do you know that qty 22 is for l_id 1 and qty 10 for l_id 2 and not vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation

```
select t.one + t.two as total_qty, 
       t.*
from
(
  select sum(case when t3.l_id = 1 then t2.qty end) as one,
          sum(case when t3.l_id = 2 then t2.qty end) as two,
          t1.pr_id
   from table3 t3
   join table1 t1 on t1.c_id = t3.c_id
   join table2 t2 on t1.id= t2.id and 
                     t1.pr_id = t2.pr_id
   group by t1.pr_id
) t
```